# More CSS alignment issues

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align an `<H2>` with a button on the same line. The `<H2>` has a bottom border line, and I would like the button to be just above the line.

I've tried adding to the bottom margin and/or padding, but that moves things down.

I'm attaching the rendered HTML and a screenshot of some inspects in Chrome. If there is any other information that could be helpful, please let me know.

```css
.button-xs-med {
  display:inline-block;
  width:95px;
  height:25px;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:13px;
  line-height:1;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  background:url('/content/images/workflow-wizard-button-xs-med.png') no-repeat;
}

.button-xs-med .button-text {
  display:inline-block;
  width:95px;
  height:12px;
  margin:4px 5px 0px 0px;
  font-family:'Open Sans Condensed',sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="pnlResourceSnapshotList" data-source-href="http://localhost:63595/profiles/yada/652">
  <div>
    <h2 style="margin: 0 15px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;">
      Current Resources
      <a onclick="AjaxAction('/home/setcollapse', 'POST');" class="button-xs-med" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href=".collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="contentDetails" style="float: right;">
        <span class="button-text">
          Details
        </span>
      </a>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div style="margin: 0 15px;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; padding:5px 0px;border-bottom:1px solid #dadada;">
      <div style="padding: 0;">
        Text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="margin: 0 15px; ">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; padding:5px 0px;border-bottom:1px solid #dadada;">
      <div style="padding: 0;">
        Text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like your button is higher than h2. You could make h2 line-height same as button height, or add some top padding to h2. The other solution would be to make h2 relative position and the button absolute, than control the button with for example: `right: 0; bottom: 0;`.

Comment: That looks better, but I'm not sure how you changed it.

Comment: Is there another way to have the button right aligned in the div/h2 without `float`?

Answer (score 0):

Without the css for your button this is going to be a bit of a guess. It looks to me like your button is too big for the line. The height of the line is set by non-inline and non-floating elements (both of which your anchor is). In order to correct this, either increase the h2 font-size, increase the line-height of the h2, or adjust the styling of the anchor so that it's not floating or inline.

You could do it with some position relative (with negative top) as well but you'll have to tinker a bit and decide which you like best.

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested by @skobaljic, you can use `absolute` positioning... however the `<h2>` element has to be set to `relative` positioning. Using this method, there will be no need to use `float`.

```
/* Adjust your css */
h2 {
    position: relative;
}

.button-xs-med {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Then adjust your html - note that `style="float: right;"` has been removed from the anchor tag.

```
<h2 style="margin: 0px 15px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218); position: relative;">
      Current Resources
      <a style="" aria-controls="contentDetails" aria-expanded="false" href=".collapse" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" class="button-xs-med" onclick="AjaxAction('/home/setcollapse', 'POST');">
        <span class="button-text">
          Details
        </span>
      </a>
</h2>
```